# Reading xmldata through parser

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

Hello Everyone I am Reading Data as a xmlElemet through parser

I am getting error Like..'\b', hexadecimal value 0x08, is an invalid character

I Read this string..
Thanks..

```
        XElement xParser = null;
            string sPwd = null;
            string sKey1 = null;
            string sKey2 = null;
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            string soutxml = "";

            soutxml = encoding.GetString(sEncData);
           xParser = XElement.Parse(soutxml);

        IEnumerable<XElement> elemsValidations =
              from el in xParser.Elements("EmailPwd")
             select el;

        foreach (XElement elemValidation in elemsValidations)
        {
            sPwd = elemValidation.Element("EncPwd").Value;
            sKey1 = elemValidation.Element("Key1").Value;
            sKey2 = elemValidation.Element("Key2").Value;
        }

            byte[] Key1 = encoding.GetBytes(sKey1);
            byte[] Key2 = encoding.GetBytes(sKey2);
            byte[] Data = encoding.GetBytes(sPwd);

            // Decrypt the buffer back to a string.
            string Final = DecryptTextFromMemory(Data, Key1, Key2);

            return Final;
```

This data is actual data output..

```
- <EmailPwd>
- <EncPwd>
- <![CDATA[ ?????@]Z
  ]]> 
  </EncPwd>
- <Key1>
- <![CDATA[ ~??s????E&?3??2?3I?????
  ]]> 
  </Key1>
- <Key2>
- <![CDATA[ ???h?6
  ]]> 
  </Key2>
  </EmailPwd>
```

Comment: where is the string? and which parser are you using? any code sample?

Comment: I Will send u some ex. I Reading this data just see my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data appears to have a char  0x08 in it. According to [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char) this is not valid XML so the parser is correct in raising an error

You have to change the data to be valid XML - by changing with the invalid characters.
and /or asking the supplier of the data to provide XML which they are not currently doing.